# ImportError - Not finding Python Packages

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am stuck trying to get an application via Apache web server. I keep getting the following error.

```
ImportError: No module named flask
```

I believe this is because it might be pointing to the wrong Python. I had anaconda, but have removed that. When I check to see all the versions of Python, the following show up.

```
which -a python

/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python

Error: No module named flask
```

When I print the environment variables, here is the following:

```
printenv

PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

The packages are all there as I have verified that with a pip freeze. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been stuck on this for a while. Thanks!

Comment: are you using a virtual environment!!?

Comment: I am unsure. I am trying to use Apache to configure my application. Thanks for your prompt reply.

Comment: Apache is just webserver you have to make sure you are using the right Python interpreter where your packages are installed.

Comment: `pip install flask` will install the package

Comment: All the packages are there. My application that I am attempting to run locally is not.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is quiet unclear answering from what i understood.

It seems like you have 2 python installed on your device. First find for which python all the modules are installed . Then simply mention the path of that python on the top of your script. If your case

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

or

```
#!/usr/local/env python
```

Comment: Is there a way to change that path to /usr/bin/env instead of explicitly putting it in a python script? Thanks!